# Protractor: Error: ReferenceError: describle is not defined

Tags: automation, jasmine, protractor

I tried to run protractor test but there is error shows up on the command prompt. I put the spec file and config file at the same directory. Below is the content of the file.

spec.js

```
describle("Freelance Website", function () {
    it("Sign Up", function (){
        browser.get("https://www.freelancer.com/");
    }); 
});
```

config.js

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine', 
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['spec.js']
}
```

I run the protractor test with following command protractor conf.js. What is the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure `describle` is supposed to be spelled with an `l`?

Answer (score 0):

please correct the  spelling of `describe`. Refer the below code

```
describe("A suite is just a function", function() {
  var a;
  it("and so is a spec", function() {
    a = true;
    expect(a).toBe(true);
  });
});
```